# Akka Pattern Match on Generic Type

Tags: scala, generics, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream

I have an Actor instance as defined like this:

```
class KafkaPublisher[T <: KafkaMessage] extends Actor {

  override final def receive = {
    case ProducerStreamActivated(_, stream: SourceQueueWithComplete[T]) =>
      context.become(active(stream))

    case other => println("KafkaPublisher got some unknown message while producing: " + other)
  }

  def active(stream: SourceQueueWithComplete[T]): Receive = super.receive orElse {
    case msg: T =>
      stream.offer(msg)

    case other => println("KafkaPublisher got the unknown message while producing: " + other)
  }
}
object KafkaPublisher {

  def props[T <: KafkaMessage](implicit tag: ClassTag[T]) = Props(new KafkaPublisher[T])
}
```

Where the KafkaMessage is a marker trait and every message that I want to publish to Kafka will extend this marker trait. I have a supervisor Actor that actually will create instances of this KafkaPublisher Actor depending on the type of Kafka message. For example.,

```
case class MeterData(id: String, meterReadings: Map[DateTime, String]) extends KafkaMessage
```

So in my SupervisorActor, I create an instance of my PublisherActor like this:

```
def actorFor(props: Props, actorName: String) = context.actorOf(props, actorName)
val actorRef = actorFor(KafkaPublisher.props[MeterData], "meter-data-actor")
```

Similarly, I create the corresponding Akka stream flow for the given KafkaMessage type.

So my question is, would this KafkaPublisher actor pattern match on the MeterData, given that I have a generic pattern matching defined. Is the ClassTag in my props method just enough so that I can get past the type erasure? Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching on a generic type `T` should work, when there an implicit `ClassTag[T]` in scope. So it should be enough to provide and store a `ClassTag` in your `KafkaPublisher`:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class KafkaPublisher[T <: KafkaMessage : ClassTag] {
  /* ... */
}

object KafkaPublisher {
  def props[T <: KafkaMessage : ClassTag] = Props(new KafkaPublisher[T])
}
```

If the type `T` is concrete at the `props` call site, or it's generic but there is an implicit `ClassTag[T]` there, then you can just call `props` as usual: `actorFor(KafkaPublisher.props[MeterData], "meter-data-actor")`

Comment: There is also an TypeTag if you need type informations of more nested types. I can highly recommend to read https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html if you are interested in more informations about ClassTag and TypeTag.